# Draw a polyline between two coordinates in Xcode

Tags: ios, mapkit

I would like to draw a POLY-LINE between two or more given coordinates on the map(poly-line and not the route). Imagine I have 2 dropped pins on the map and I need to draw a straight line from the first dropped pin to the second dropped pin.

Answer (score 8):

In Interface file

```
MKPolyline* _routeLine;
MKPolylineView* _routeLineView;
```

In Implementation file

Store all the coordinates in

```
NSMutablrArray *routeLatitudes
```

then

```
MKMapPoint* pointArr = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * [routeLatitudes count]); 
for(int idx = 0; idx < [routeLatitudes count]; idx++)
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D workingCoordinate;       
    workingCoordinate.latitude=[[routeLatitudes objectAtIndex:idx] doubleValue];
    workingCoordinate.longitude=[[routeLongitudes objectAtIndex:idx] doubleValue];  
    MKMapPoint point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(workingCoordinate);
    pointArr[idx] = point;      
}   
// create the polyline based on the array of points. 
routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pointArr count:[routeLatitudes count]];
[mapViewHome addOverlay:self.routeLine];
free(pointArr);
```

and Overlay delegate

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
 {
       MKOverlayView* overlayView = nil;

   if(overlay == routeLine)
   {
        routeLineView = [[[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:self.routeLine] autorelease];
        routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.945 green:0.027 blue:0.957  alpha:1];
        routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.945 green:0.027 blue:0.957 alpha:1];
        routeLineView.lineWidth = 4;

        overlayView = routeLineView;
    }
    return overlayView;
 }
```

Hope this helps

**Edited Code**

here is the code to get NsMutableArray of coordinates.

call this function

```
NSString * saddr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",StartCoordinate.latitude, StartCoordinate.longitude];
NSString* daddr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",EndCoordinate.latitude, EndCoordinate.longitude];
routeLatitudes=[[[self getDirectionRoutesFrom:[saddr copy] to:[daddr mutableCopy]] mutableCopy] retain];
```

function definition

```
 -(NSMutableArray *)getDirectionRoutesFrom:(NSString *)saddr1 to:(NSString *)daddr
{
NSString* apiUrlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?output=dragdir&saddr=%@&daddr=%@", saddr1, daddr];
NSURL* apiUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:apiUrlStr];    
//NSString *apiResponse = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:apiUrl];
NSString *apiResponse = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:apiUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding   error:nil];
NSString* encodedPoints = [apiResponse stringByMatching:@"points:\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"" capture:1L];
//NSMutableArray *temparr=[[MapViewController decodePolyLine:[encodedPoints mutableCopy]] retain];
return [[self decodePolyLine:[encodedPoints mutableCopy]] retain];
//return temparr;
}
```

and

```
 -(NSMutableArray *)decodePolyLine: (NSMutableString *)encoded {
[encoded replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\" withString:@"\\"
                            options:NSLiteralSearch
                              range:NSMakeRange(0,     [encoded length])];
NSInteger len = [encoded length];
NSInteger index = 0;
NSMutableArray *array = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
NSInteger lat=0;
NSInteger lng=0;
while (index < len) {
    NSInteger b;
    NSInteger shift = 0;
    NSInteger result = 0;
    do {
        b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
        result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
        shift += 5;
    } while (b >= 0x20);
    NSInteger dlat = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
    lat += dlat;
    shift = 0;
    result = 0;
    do {
        b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
        result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
        shift += 5;
    } while (b >= 0x20);
    NSInteger dlng = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
    lng += dlng;
    NSNumber *latitude = [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lat * 1e-5] autorelease];
    NSNumber *longitude = [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lng * 1e-5] autorelease];
    printf("[%f,", [latitude doubleValue]);
    printf("%f]", [longitude doubleValue]);
    CLLocation *loc = [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[latitude floatValue] longitude:[longitude floatValue]] autorelease];
    [array addObject:loc];
}

return array;
 }
```

include RegexKitLite.h in your file.

Comment: Thanks Mahendra for your help,
but wrote your code, after i filled the array. but now i am receiving and error "Thread 1: signal sigabrt"
what is is error?

Comment: set property for both routeLineView and routeLine variables and use with self.

self.routeLine and self.routeLineView.

Comment: Mahendara, thanks again. i just figured out that i am filling the NSMutablrArray *routeLatitudes incorrectly. would you please to help me with how to store all the coordinates in NSMutablrArray.

Comment: i wrote the code and got the polylines being drawn from my point reaching an infinite point, in other words the beginning point of the line starts from the my given lat and long point, and the end of the line is infinite and not the other point.